# QuickSort implementation to sort list in place doesn't update the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, quicksort

I made an implementation of the quicksort algortihm in python3.6 using recursion. It sorts the list in place in increasing order. The problem however is that the list elements order do not change in the code and after the code is done running

If you remove the base case for the recursion and let it fail on maximum recursion depth reached and put print statements in the partition method you can see it changing the elements in the list

```
def partition(arr, start, end):
    pivot = arr[end]
    ix = start
    for i in range(start, end):
        print("i = ", i)
        if arr[i] <= pivot:
            arr[i], arr[ix] = arr[ix], arr[i]
            ix += 1
    arr[ix], arr[end] = arr[end], arr[ix]
    return ix

def quick_sort(arr, start, end):
    if start < end: return arr
    ix = partition(arr, start, end)
    quick_sort(arr, start, ix-1)
    quick_sort(arr, ix+1, end)

arr = [2,4,7,8,9,1,3,5,6,12,32]

print("before", arr)
print("output", quick_sort(arr, 0, len(ans)-1))
print("after", arr)

OUTPUT 
before [2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 5, 6, 12, 32]
output [2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 5, 6, 12, 32]
after [2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 5, 6, 12, 32]
```

Comment: Just a small side note, but an [mcve] should be complete. As is, for example, `ans` is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
if start < end: return arr
```

The logic is reversed. It should be

```
if start > end: return arr
```

However, because your function operates in-place, it shouldn't return anything, so it's best to make it

```
if start > end: return
```

You will see that `quick_sort(arr, 0, len(ans)-1)` will return `None`, but after the function call, `arr` will be sorted.